# Encoding of integer arithmetic counting using Lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, arithmetic

Does anyone know a way of showing an encoding of integer arithmetic counting using Lambda Calculus?

Any references related to this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

arithmatic means normal addition,negation, etc. kind of things, you can observe this 
as 
let say we expect from a programming language that it should be capable of doing arith-metical calculations. Numbers can be represented in lambda calculus starting from zero and writing “suc(zero)” to represent 1, “suc(suc(zero))” to represent 2, and soon. In the lambda calculus we can only define new functions. Numbers will be definedas functions using the following approach: zero can be defined as

λs.(λz.z)

1 ≡ λsz.s(z)

2 ≡ λsz.s(s(z))

3 ≡ λsz.s(s(s(z)))

for more info go through this PDF [1]

[1]http://www.utdallas.edu/~gupta/courses/apl/lambda.pdf

Comment: This only defines the natural numbers.